# iOS 9: Frame no longer set in viewWillAppear after UINavigationController pushViewController

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios9

I'm trying to solve a view placement bug that has arisen as of iOS 9. I am instantiating a view controller from a xib file (non-autolayout) and then pushing this onto my `UINavigationController`.

The problem is that when the view controller's `viewWillAppear` method is called, its frame has not yet been adjusted to the navigation controller's size and is still what was set in the xib file. It doesn't get set properly now until `viewDidAppear`.

This is completely screwing up my code. Does anyone know precisely what has changed that is causing this and what is the best way to handle it? I don't want to wait until `viewDidAppear` because this will look bad and make for a poor user experience.

Comment: I am encountering the same issue.  Upon further inspection it looks like the child view hasn't even been added to the UINavigationController's view yet (view.superview == nil)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am also looking for the best fix.

My temporary one is to call the code that was in "viewDidAppear" in "viewDidLayoutSubviews". That way, my code will get called as soon as the frames are set.

But, make sure to add a boolean or something so that your code doesn't get called every time viewDidLayoutSubviews is called

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
   if (didLayoutSubviews == NO){
       didLayoutSubviews = YES;
       // perform code that was in viewWillAppear
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, this did the trick! Unfortunate that this is necessary. `viewWillAppear` was the perfect conceptual place to put this code previously. Now it feels like we have to do a hack to do what came naturally before. :(

Answer (score 0):

I occurred this issue too,

try to uncheck option "Resize View From NIB" from storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the layout code from `viewWillAppear` to `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit updated NickProvost's answer:

```
private var loadViewToken: dispatch_once_t = 0

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    dispatch_once(&loadViewToken) { [weak self] in
        if let wSelf = self {
            wSelf.setupView()
        }
    }
}
```