# viewDidLayoutSubviews no longer called when popping top view with UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, viewdidlayoutsubviews

iOS 10, the gift that keeps on breaking, seems to have changed another behavior.

Assume two UIViewControllers are pushed onto a UINavigationController.

On iOS 8/9, calling `navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` to pop the top UIViewController (say VC2) caused `viewDidLayoutSubviews` on the bottom view controller (say VC1) to get called.

We relied on this to refresh VC1. Sometimes VC2 adds subviews to VC1 (via the data model), and this needs to get reflected when popping back to VC1.

Accurate frame information is required. We can't use `viewWillAppear` because [frame data is wrong on iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662851/ios-9-frame-no-longer-set-in-viewwillappear-after-uinavigationcontroller-pushvi). The problem with `viewDidAppear` is that there is a momentary glitch between seeing the view initially and the adjustment.

Now VC1's `viewDidLayoutSubviews` does not get invoked when popping VC2.

1) Is this a bug for `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to not get invoked?

2) What's the right way to refresh view controllers when popping with UINavigationController?

Comment: I assume `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called at some point. Is it called together with the other controller (VC2)?

Comment: @LeoNatan yes it is is called when VC1 appears the first time

Comment: Actually sounds like an acceptable behavior. If you update data source in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, that's not good.

Comment: @LeoNatan no we don't update the data source in viewDidLayoutSubviews. the data source is modified in VC2, but VC1 should reflect the new data (which causes new subviews to appear).

Comment: @Crashalot Then what I put in my answer is correct. You should update the data in `viewWillAppear` and add/update any new views as well. The new views should be setup based on the view controller's view size at the time. `viewDidLayoutSubviews` can be used as normal to adjust the subview's frames.

Comment: @rmaddy but if `viewDidLayoutSubviews` isn't getting called now, how will the new subview's frames get adjusted?

Comment: They won't need to be adjusted. As I said, you create them with the proper frame to begin with. This should always be done anyway. But you also have code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to adjust any and all subviews as needed. Keep in mind that simply dismissing VC2 does not and should not result in the view of VC1 changing size. That's why `viewDidLayoutSubview` isn't called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relying on `viewDidLayoutSubviews` was never the proper solution. `UIViewController` provides `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:` for such a use. When VC2 is popped from the navigation controller, those two methods will be called on VC1 to let you know that is will be or now is visible again.

`viewDidLayoutSubviews` should only be used to adjust view frames and layout.

`viewWill|DidAppear:` should be used to handle the view controller becoming visible originally or again. In your case you should use this to update data and add/update views as needed. Those new views should be setup based on the view controller's current frame. They will be adjusted in your implementation of `viewDidLayoutSubviews` as needed.

Comment: Sorry should have clarified that frame information is required, and it appears `viewWillAppear` does not contain proper frame data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662851/ios-9-frame-no-longer-set-in-viewwillappear-after-uinavigationcontroller-pushvi. The problem with `viewDidAppear` is that there is a momentary glitch between seeing the view initially and the adjustment.

Comment: `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is sometimes much more appropriate place to put code which specifically needs to layout view. For instance, in `viewWillAppear` the hierarchy is often incomplete and not ready yet. `viewDidAppear` is too late, as it happens after the animation. In this case, refreshing a data source is indeed not the place.

Comment: @LeoNatan precisely our assessment. So any suggestions? Also (1) is this a bug on iOS 10; (2) or is this intended behavior from now on?

Comment: @LeoNatan We don't disagree. I never said anything about laying out views in `viewWillAppear`. I stated that adjusting frames belongs in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. But that's not the question.

Comment: @Crashalot One cannot know. Open a bug report if you believe it is an issue. `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is meant to *layout* the view, not update data.

Comment: @Crashalot It will help if you clarify exactly what changes you wish to make when VC1 appears again after VC2 is dismissed.

Comment: @LeoNatan sorry imprecise wording. yes, the view layout changes as more subviews are added. will update q.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But if `viewDidLayoutSubviews` isn't getting called now, how will the new subview's frames get adjusted?

Comment: Thanks to you both rmaddy and @LeoNatan.

Comment: @LeoNatan hi again. stumbled across this SO answer which suggests `viewDidLayoutSubviews` does not guarantee frame information is ready for certain cases of AutoLayout: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28622285/144088. `viewWillAppear` does not provide accurate information on iOS 9, so which function do we use for accurate frame information?

Comment: @Crashalot Why do you need accurate frame information with AL? The whole point is not to need that. If you have specific designs for iPhone/iPad, the correct way is to consult the size class of the controller. This will always be accurate at `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: @LeoNatan good question. We need a camera preview layer to assume the frame of a view that is connected via AL to the edges of a UIViewController's main view. Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: @Crashalot Yeah, that's going to be a mess. You can observe the `bounds` and `center` properties and set it there. Do not observe the `frame`. Or better, wrap that layer in a view and then the system will do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

I will complement rmaddy's answer. You need to decouple performing layout and updating your data. If your flow is such that data should updated as the view is about to appear, you should update your controller's view-backing data in `viewWillAppear:`, reload your views and then mark the view as needing layout using `setNeedsLayout`. This will cause the system to perform a layout on the controller's view, and will trigger the layout. This way, you can ensure the layout is performed once the view is ready, and not before (as often the case is in `viewWillAppear:`.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant in my answer before it became clear that the goal was to add new views. I generalized that in my answer by simply stating that `viewWillAppear` should be used to handle the view becoming visible. In this case, that handling is to add new views and refresh data.

Comment: @rmaddy It is often confusing. I am used to people recommeding the `viewWillAppear` route of performing layout on the view, which is often incorrect. Af first, I read your answer like that.

Comment: Do you need to call `layoutIfNeeded` as well as `setNeedsLayout`?

Comment: No. the system will know it needs to layout before display.