# Is there a way to change the height of a UINavigationBar in a UINavigationController Swift Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Is there a way to change (namely, decrease) the height of a UINavigationBar in a UINavigationController? I have tried the following to no avail:

```
extension UINavigationBar {

override open func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 10)
    }

}

class CustomNavigationController : UINavigationController {

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        navigationBar.frame.size.height = 10
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below codes,

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
   super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
   let height = CGFloat(72)
   navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: height)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a question: UINavigationControllers have `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`, but not `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` so where should I implement the above block of code? Or should I use `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: Is this what you are referring to?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751366/how-can-i-change-height-of-navigation-bar-swift-3?rq=1

Comment: No you have to write the code inside the UINavigationController's class

Comment: I think viewDidLayoutSubviews() was deprecated in iOS 11 (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39780470/viewdidlayoutsubviews-no-longer-called-when-popping-top-view-with-uinavigationco))